# PostgreSQL can I inherit search_path variable from a "group role"?

Tags: postgresql, roles, search-path

I know I can define the search_path variable for a login this way:

```
ALTER ROLE myrole SET search_path=public, foo, bar;
```

But if I use a lot of logins I will also use groups (groups in pgadmin which are in fact roles). I would like to define the search_path variable on group level, so I remove this previous SET and instead wrote:

```
ALTER ROLE mygroup SET search_path=public, foo, bar;
```

And just define login as a member of the group

```
GRANT mygroup TO myrole
```

Now, a `SHOW search_path;` show me only the default search-path `"$user",public`. Is there a way to define variables for the group level (so with inheritance)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No you can't do that. The search_path is a variable not a grant-able object.